# How do I find java code coverage using jcov

Tags: java

To know which testcase has covered which part of the code including classes, methods, branches, lines so as to differentiate passed and failed testcases.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this - https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/CodeTools/JCov+FAQ.
Jcov will generate results in a xml file.